# Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead does nothing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Angular JS -  v1.2.0-rc.3
Angular Bootstrap - 0.12.0

Controller:

```
app.controller('controlsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.selected = undefined;

    $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
        return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
            params: {
                address: val,
                sensor: false
            }
        }).success(function(response){
            return response.data.results.map(function(item){
                return item.formatted_address;
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

Jade:

```
input(type='text'
        ng-model='asyncSelected'
        placeholder='find...'
        typeahead='address for address in getLocation($viewValue)'
        typeahead-loading='loadingLocations'
        class='form-control')
```

Result:

> Nothing

I have tried putting a button that calls `getLocation` in place of the input  and it calls the function OK. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Ian have you added dependency on the `ui.bootstrap` to your app ?

Comment: The CSS yes. It needs javascript too?

Comment: yes please see here for working demo http://jsbin.com/suveba/2/edit

Comment: Oh yes I have all those references already. I thought you meant native bootstrap js.

Comment: @sylwester I see what you were getting at now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` *and*
   `ui-bootstrap.min.js`. Either one or the other.
2. Remember to add the dependency to the app's module.

   ```
       var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
   ```